# Ionic2: Package com.my.app has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: ionic2

I created one application using Ionic2 and when i run the command `ionic cordova run android --prod --release` I am getting an error

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl
971492117.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml]
```

Do anyone know how to fix this error?

NB: I have seen similar questions all of them are for native application development.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? Because I have exactly the same problem. Thanks by advance

Comment: @RemiP, yes. I followed the below method. First of all you have to build your application in production mode. Then open Android studio and run your application or sign your apk then run

Answer (score 7):

You cannot install a package build with `--release` without signing it. See this question on [Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-release-installation-ionic-invalidate-certificate/114136/4)

Try `ionic cordova run android --prod` to install an unsigned app to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have another app installed with the same name, signed with another type of key. Ie in your device you the app singed with a release key. Other possibility is there is an app in your device with a newer version.

Comment: I have faced this issue before, when App is not cleanly uninstalled you will face this issue. Please go to the settings in phone to check the Apps in phone, sometimes App will not visible in phone but it will be there.

Comment: Try with other device too.